# device types in CreateAsyncFind function of UPnP

Tags: visual-c++, upnp

Please tell me what is range of values I can give in device type parameter of CreateAsyncFind() function. How it detects the devices basis on string given ???
 Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, You should also look at the specification at: http://upnp.org/

Comment: I already checked on msdn site but it didnt make me clear how it searches and if I want to search for a particular type of device what string should I give... However, I didnt check upnp.org, I will explore it now as well... Thanks !

Comment: Meanwhile, If u have any specific answer of query kindly reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Each UPnP device has its own unique type and URI, you will need to supply the URI in your call to `CreateAsyncFind()`. As an example to search for a MediaServer:3 device you would use `urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:3`.
Checkout [Device Categories](http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/sdcps/) for a list of different device categories.